# Assign a dynamic value to object from json

Tags: angularjs, json

I've built a panorama viewer using Pannellum, where I pass options into the default config to generate a view like so;

```
var panoOptionDefaults = {
            type: "equirectangular",
            haov: imageXRes,
            vaov :imageYRes,
            minPitch : 0,
            maxPitch : 0,
            minYaw : (imageYRes * 2) * -1,
            maxYaw : (imageYRes * 2),
            autoLoad : true,
            mouseZoom : false,
            showControls : false,
            hfov:imageXRes * 2, // Zoom - positive number zooms out / negative number zooms in 
            panorama: $scope.currentProfile.panorama.image, //value in json, returns error
            hotSpotDebug : false,
            hotSpots: [ // Dynamic Value
                {
                    "pitch": -9.0,
                    "yaw": -1.0,
                    "cssClass": "custom-hotspot",
                    "createTooltipFunc": hotspot,
                    "createTooltipArgs": "Radios for Communication"
                }
             ]
           }
```

What I'm trying to do is have the value of 'panaroma' come through from my response.data Get method. I've already written a working angular service that returns a profile.json based on an attribute and a get method that returns this json result for each directive that has individual data here ;

```
            $scope.currentProfile = {}; / /creates object
        profiles.getProfile().then(function(response){
            $scope.currentProfile = response.data; //returns data and assigns to $scope
        });
```

Comment: you want to get some values from response.data?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, yes i do

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I'm trying to have the 'panorama' value in my panoOptionDefaults  object come through from the json I am requesting in my getProfiles method

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to be sure since your answer in still lacking some key details (like when are you using the `panoOptionsDefault` object), but I suspect that your issue is due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript.

The comment on the line that assigns `panorama` says "returns error", but you don't specify the error message. I suspect that error is occurring because the value of `$scope.currentProfile` has not been assigned yet. If so, you need to wait until the AJAX call that retrieves that data is complete before you use `panoOptionsDefault`.

So you need to do something like this:

```
profiles.getProfile().then(function(response){
    $scope.currentProfile = response.data;
    // Now you can use panoOptionsDefault
    SomeCall(panoOptionsDefault);
});
```